# How to convert a hex string to bytes?

Tags: python, encoding, hex, byte

I need to send a byte string like this one to a UDP socket

```
request=b'\x00\x01\x02\xc3\x68\x44\xcc\x61\x0e\x05\x05'
```

This is a connection request, and I am able to create the connection,

The third byte `\x02` is a tag number that I would like to change from the code, so I did the following

```
request = b'\x00\x01' + tag.to_bytes(1,'little') + b'\x02\xc3\x68\x44\xcc\x61\x0e\05\05'
```

where `tag` is the variable that stores my tag number

When I send this request to the socket it does not work. When printing the request the reason is clear: it has changed. In the above example, assuming that `tag == 2`,

```
>>> request = b'\x00\x01' + number.to_bytes(1,'little') + b'\x02\xc3\x68\x44\xcc\x61\x0e\05\05'
>>> print(request)
b'\x00\x01\x02\x02\xc3hD\xcca\x0e\x05\x05'
```

while what I was expecting was

```
request=b'\x00\x01\x02\xc3\x68\x44\xcc\x61\x0e\05\05'
```

It seems that other people has had similar problems,
[String to Bytes Python without change in encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48367128/string-to-bytes-python-without-change-in-encoding)
attributing the problem to the way the `print()` function represents the string. In my case, if I send the byte string that includes the `tag` variable, I am unable to create a connection, so looks like the underlying code in the socket library behaves similarly to the `print()` function.

I have also tried [How to create python bytes object from long hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443967/how-to-create-python-bytes-object-from-long-hex-string) with no success. I can put together a hex string, but then I get the same problem as before

```
>>> print(bytes.fromhex('000102c36844cc610e0505'))
b'\x00\x01\x02\xc3hD\xcca\x0e\x05\x05'
```

How can I get a bytes string representation of the string `\x00\x01\x02\xc3hD\xcca\x0e\x05\x05`?

Comment: There are some good answers & comments covering this here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690025/print-bytes-to-hex). the answer from @jfs covers how to print your hex as a string and the reasons behind why it displays differently.

Comment: If you want to _remove_ the third byte (`\x02`), why are you including it in the part after `tag.to_bytes(1,'little')`?

Comment: BTW, `b'\x00\x01\x02\xc3\x68\x44\xcc\x61\x0e\x05\x05'` is the same thing as `b'\x00\x01\x02\xc3hD\xcca\x0e\x05\x05'`. Try `print(b'\x00\x01\x02\xc3\x68\x44\xcc\x61\x0e\x05\x05')` and see for yourself.

Comment: python for unprintable values display hex codes but for printable values it prints its chars and `print(b'\x68\x44')` gives `b'hD'` - but there are the same bytes and `b'\x68\x44' == b'hD'` gives `True`. And `b'hD'[0], b'\x68\x44'[0]` gives the same values `(104,104)`. All your problem can be only in `tag` value. Maybe it has to be converted in different way. Maybe it has to be char `"2"` (`'x32'` - `hex(ord('2'))`) instead of number `2` (and `\x02`)

Comment: Thanks to all of you that replied. At the end, when I wrote _When I send this request to the socket it does not work_ I was wrong (I was making an error elsewhere). It works. What means,  as @zvone pointed, that b'\x00\x01\x02\xc3\x68\x44\xcc\x61\x0e\x05\x05' and b'\x00\x01\x02\xc3hD\xcca\x0e\x05\x05'are the same thing. I still do not understand why python represents \xc3\x68\x44\xcc like xc3hD\xcca when using the print() function.

Comment: @CarlesRoch-Cunill Python represents all printable ascii characters as the ascii characters and only shows the others as hex, because that is shorter and easier to understand. You would not want `b'ABCDE'` to show up as `b'\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45'`, would you?

Comment: Thanks @zvone for your clarification. However, in this case, yes!, I wanted to send `b'\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45'` as this is what the protocol (RTP) is expecting. My original problem was the RTP packets I was creating didn't contain the information I sent. To debug I print() the request and is when I found the representation changed. At the end I found that seems to be only print() that changes the representation. The socket accepts correctly the characters I am sending. I had made a mistake and I though the socket was also changing the representation the same as print().